# Finding an old version of Git

Tags: git, dmg-image

I have just downloaded the .dmg file for the latest version of Git for my Mac with OS X 10.7.5. When I type:

```
git --version
```

I get:

```
Illegal instruction: 4
```

This apparently means that my installation contains instructions that my OS doesn't understand.

In order to get around this, I was going to try to download an earlier version of Git.

I've searched but I can't seem to find a .dmg for an older version of Git.

Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1):

1) to be pedantic it could also mean your git app is corrupt and the corruption is hitting an illegal opcode

2) technically you don't want an older git but a git compiled for an older chip. Git version irrelevant, though you'll find correlation between git ages and compiler flags for new chips.  Find out what chip you have and try the googles for that.

3) if you're skilled enough to need git you may want to try macports or homebrew.